# Django-CKEditor won't render images

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I've installed Django-CKEditor and configurated it for development purposes.

Now I can edit text and save it to db as text field. But with inserting images I have major problems...

I can insert image and it seems to save properly to local host (to correct folder) but when rendering image to preview or text editor I get only broken image picture.
Apparently I haven't configured settings.py correctly. Main items from settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'media/uploads/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PREFIX = 'media/uploads/'
```

Also tried similar configuration than django-ckeditor testproject [has](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/blob/master/test_project/test_project/settings.py) but faced similar broken rendering images.

I'm using windows environment for development. Django-ckeditor version is [4.0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor)

Any ideas what is wrong or where to start solving this?

Comment: When investigating htmls it seems that e.g. when browsing images on server ckeditor fetches all saved images from local host and shows them as broken images. From HTML `<img src="media\uploads\2013\09\19\Penguins_thumb.jpg">` => correct place but still broken image. First I thought that problem is with different kind of slashes (windows uses backslashes) and changed settings.py to contain: `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join('media', 'uploads')` but no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause.

After debugging it found out that django-ckeditor has problems with Windows back-slashes.
First I made my own correction but finally also found out that this has been already reported and correction proposal also made but not yet merged to master branch:

[Fixing trouble with backward slashes in Windows](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/pull/41)

Comment: This ist merged now and using the standard [https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

try collecting all static files
Use following in shell

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Look into this link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: According to [django-ckeditor issues](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/issues/57) it's not required during development phase. So, guess that isn't the problem (will still try that later)

Comment: I faced same issue, I tried same thing and worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-vckeditor](https://github.com/valsorym/django-vckeditor) - it is easier to install and configure. For files uploaded via FTP or existing thumbnails will be created automatically.

Comment: Link is dead, and there is no existence of a project **django-vckeditor** on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had correct urls but images were still not rendering until I remembered to mark the html as safe in the template (i.e. `{{my_model.my_text_field|safe}}`)