# django-ckeditor image upload giving wrong url of the image

Tags: django, django-forms, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

When I try text editing and other text related stuffs and save it, the editor does its job nicely. But when I try to upload an image it just take a different url. I am on windows. Is it because of this, cause I saw a post on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894044/django-ckeditor-wont-render-images), but it didn't helped me either. It does get saved and they each have their own thumbnails too. But its just that the wrong urls.
I checked the src of the image, and it was like this,

`<img alt="" src="/media/3/10/17Hydrangeas.jpg" />`

But it should have been like this,

`<img alt="" src="/media/2013/10/17/Hydrangeas.jpg" />`

And sometimes the src of the image is just like this,

`<img alt="" src="/media/3/10/17" />`

This is the snippet of my settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'C:/Users/Nanyoo/web/demo/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Nanyoo/web/demo/media'
```

I've included its url in my urls.py:

```
(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from time import time


def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    body = models.TextField()
```

In the forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class BlogForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=SummernoteWidget())
    body = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

In the index.html:

```
        {% for blog in blogs %}
        <div id="page">
                <h1>{{ blog.title | safe}}</h1>
                <p>{{ blog.body | safe}}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

my form in the html:

```
{% block content %} 
    <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset id="create_blog">
        {{form.media}}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Post Blog" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Looks like the problem's in `get_upload_file_name`. Where are the pictures actually being saved in your file system?

Comment: In the media dir... And I guess I am not using the image attribute of the my model, because I am using the editor's image upload feature to place it in my body. Or am I wrong? Please correct my if I am wrong sir.

Comment: Sorry you're right I'm being an idiot :-).

Comment: No, problem :) ! Or is it maybe because I didn't place an `uploads` as the suffix in the ckupload path like this:
`CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'C:/Users/Nanyoo/web/demo/media/uploads'` ??

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic` before using `CKEditor`? It's always worked out of the box for me so this is an odd one.

Comment: Oh! No. I did it after I added it in the installed apps. Is this the problem???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39436/discussion-between-garry-cairns-and-robin)

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of a time getting django-ckeditor up and running with my Django app, but eventually hacked my way through to being able to serve uploaded files on the local machine (during development/testing).

First thing I suggest doing - if you haven't done so already - is read [Django's documentation regarding static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). It may help in getting a better idea as to how things are configured and why.

From the [django-ckeditor installation documentation](https://github.com/riklaunim/django-ckeditor#installation), step 4 outlines the purpose of `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH` This works similarly to Django's built-in `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT`, where the path provided isn't necessarily the path in which the file is stored. You must specify a path to store the file upon upload. This may be done by making sure you have a `MEDIA_URL` global variable declared within your projects settings file.

Once you have the initial setup complete, the final step is to enable Django to serve the files you're working with locally. **Please note: This method is to be used for development and debugging purposes only. Do not deploy your code with the following snippet included.**

You may read more on this method via Django's static file how-to, within the ["Serving static files during development"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) section.

In your project's urls.py file, add the following bit of code, enabling Django to serve your local data.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # existing url patterns,
    # ...,
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

From there, you should be all set.

Just as a quick disclaimer: I am by far a seasoned professional. This method is what has worked for me, given my specific setup and environment. Results may vary.

Hope this helps to get you headed in the right direction. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH is relative to MEDIA_ROOT.

https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#id2

In your case it should be

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = ''

This worked for me. To be honest, all these *_PATH issues were probably the hardest parts of Django for me.

UPD: I see that probably your issue was of some other sort. However I noticed the error in your configuration, that's why I wanted to fix that, since I had troubles with that and other people may find this issue and my answer too. Maybe your configuration was even right, if they've changed the defaults since the time of your post.

Answer (score 0):

I made it !!!

Problem solved !!!!!!

I have the same problem just as you.

Did you solve that?

Did you change

> CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

to something else?? Don't change if wrong.

Every time after I successfully upload the picture to the server using django-ckeditor, the django-ckeditor would request a URL which looks like this

```
uploads/2015/06/11/app_software_360.jpg
```

And that indicates the browser is requesting to

localhost:8000/somewhere/someplace/uploads/2015/06/11/app_software_360.jpg

but not localhost:8000/media/uploads/2015/06/11/app_software_360.jpg This is the actually right URL location, but django-ckeditor just can not find it out. I guess this has something to do with the settings.py

You can check out this page github [issue](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/198)

By adding these to settings.py

> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
>
> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

It works!

Thumb up if you think this is helpful. :)